# Get string from a idhttp get

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

currently I am able to run a command but i cant figure out how to get the result into a string.

I do a get like so

```
idhttp1.get('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/',TStream(nil));
```

and everything seems to run ok, in wireshark i can see the results from that command. Now if i do

`HTML := idhttp1.get('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/');`

it will freeze up the app, in wireshark i can see it sent the GET and got a response, but dont know why it freezes up.  HTML is just a string var.

EDIT FULL CODE

BUTTON CLICK
 `login(EUserName.Text,EPassWord.Text);`

```
    procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
 Params: TStringList;
 html : string;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('user='+name);
    Params.Add('pass='+pass);
    Params.Add('sublogin=Login');


    //post password/username
     IdHTTP1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/', Params);
    //get the grid source
     HTML := idhttp1.Get('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/');

  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
llogin.Caption := 'Logged In';
end;
```

RESPONCE
The responce i get says `Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n` and `Content-Type: text/html\r\n`  dont know if that matters.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to talk about a memo? Do you know how to use a memo or not? Or is the issue with the GET? Make it easy by concentrating on one problem. I suspect it's the GET. Could you really not find sample code for that? It's as if you did no research at all.

Comment: The code in the question is fine, the line that assigns to HTML. Your problem is in the code we cannot see. Probably. Did you try making a very simple program that just calls Get?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is all of the code that i change from it freezing and not freezing, I dont even use HTML anywhere else.  Ill post all code its about 10 lines..give me a sec to update it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now can you see why i posted it here? I dont understand why it freezes. No EXAMPLE can tell me either?

Comment: If your program freezes, then you need to show an MCVE

Comment: Chunked Http responses cause the Get to block. The persistent connection continuously receives data from the server.

Comment: @mjn is there anything i can do to x amount of blocks? or a size? as the replay i get has a size for the reply?

Comment: `TIdHTTP` supports chunked responses.  The only way chunking would block `Get()` is if either the chunks themselves are malformed (unlikely), or if the server is sending endless chunks (ie, is streaming/pushing live data). `TIdHTTP` does not support reading pushed data, but its [hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20140305.en.aspx) allows you to read pushed data manually.

Comment: However, since the `Content-Type` is `text/html` then the server is not sending streaming data.  It can send the HTML as chunked, though, but the chunks will end when the HTML is finished, and `Get()` will keep reading until the last chunk is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy has support for some types of streamed HTTP responses (see [New TIdHTTP hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20140305.en.aspx)), but this will only help if the server uses multipart/* responses. The linked blog article explains the details further and also shows how the Indy HTTP component can feed a MIME decoder with a continuous response stream.

If this is not applicable to your case, a workaround is to go down to the "raw" TCP layer, which means send the HTTP request using a TIdTCPClient component, and then read the response line by line (or byte by byte) from the IOHandler. This gives total control over response handling. Request and Response should be processed in a thread to decouple it from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

`TIdHTTP.Post()` returns the response data, you should not be calling `TIdHTTP.Get()` to retrieve it separately:

```
procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
  Params: TStringList;
  html : string;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('user='+name);
    Params.Add('pass='+pass);
    Params.Add('sublogin=Login');

    //post password/username
    HTML := IdHTTP1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
  llogin.Caption := 'Logged In';
end;
```

Comment: from what i saw while watching it on wireshark was , once i loged it, it sent a reply which was not much data. I cant remember exactly what it was, but seem to something like you loged in..maybe cookies or something.. but i had to then run a get to reload? i guess.. the page, and get the response of the HTML.. I will try this but i think it will just give me the text of the First reply, which seems to be nothing

Comment: It is not uncommon to have to login to one URL before another URL can then be gotten.  It is not so common to POST and then GET to the same URL, though.  An HTTP redirect is typically used to handle that instead, and `TIdHTTP` can handle redirects for you.  Without seeing the actual Wireshark capture, it is hard to say what is actually happening one way or the other.